# Get a table object from sortable table

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Say I have a table of any length, I'm able to move them about, and I want to get the table element that I released my mouse on, I have the mouse release etc from jquery + jquery.sortable for my table.

This kind of works not 100% yet, it gets the first on the list wrong if you move that but its as close as I have atm, any advice is appriciated, tbody is my table, it could be any table though. I gave up on (x,y) co-ordinate

Follows an example of code that tries to expose my idea:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     var arr2;
     $('tbody').sortable({
     start: function(e, ui) {
            arr2 = ($.map($(this).find('tr'), function(el) {
                return $(el).attr('id');
            }));
        }
    });
     $('tbody').sortable({
     stop: function(e, ui) {
      newArr = ($.map($(this).find('tr'), function(el) {
          return $(el).attr('id');
          }));
            function oldArr(arr) {
                var i=0, res = [];
                    while(i<arr.length && typeof(arr2[i]) !== 'undefined'){
                            res.push(arr[i]);
                            i++;
                            }
                return res;
            }
            outOld = oldArr(arr2);

            function findMovedFrom(arr, arr2) {
                if(arr.length == arr2.length){
                    for(j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
                        if(arr[j] !== arr2[j]){
                            if(arr[j] == arr2[j-1]){
                                return arr[j];
                            }else{
                                return arr2[j];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            alert(" from \n"+  findMovedFrom(outOld,newArr) + "\n to before \n" + newArr[(newArr.indexOf(findMovedFrom(outOld,newArr))) + 1] +  "\n" );
        }
    });      
 </script>
```

Comment: I'm presuming that by sortable you mean the [jquery ui sortable plugin](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/)?

Comment: Yes I used that to make it sortable, thought it was a straight forward jquery

Comment: elementFromPoint(x,y) isn't resolving it either it just gets someId

Comment: Sounds like you're down a rabbit hole of your own making. Start at the actual goal, what are you trying to figure out in the end? Since using Sortable, you can determine the element from `stop` or `update` since `ui.item` is passed back to these. You can also flag it with a unique class and then just call `$(".myElement")` or something like that.

Comment: The goal is to Identify where I came from on a table and where I dropped an object on that table, to display that to a user and thanks it does sound like I'm back to some other idea

Comment: @Twisty thank you for that stop seems to be able to give me enough to work with, at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly solved it messily, if anyone ever wants to find from where on a sortable table you dragged an object from and where to, where tbody is your table rows, many thanks to @Twisty

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var arr2;
     $('tbody').sortable({
     start: function(e, ui) {
            arr2 = ($.map($(this).find('tr'), function(el) {
                return $(el).attr('id');
            }));
        }
    });
     $('tbody').sortable({
     stop: function(e, ui) {
      newArr = ($.map($(this).find('tr'), function(el) {
          return $(el).attr('id');
          }));

            function oldArr(arr) {
                var i=0, res = [];
                    while(i<arr.length && typeof(arr2[i]) !== 'undefined'){
                            res.push(arr[i]);
                            i++;
                            }
                return res;
            }
            outOld = oldArr(arr2);

            function findMovedFrom(arr, arr2) {
                if(arr.length == arr2.length){
                    for(j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
                        if(arr[j] !== arr2[j]){
                            if(arr[j] == arr2[j-1] || arr2[j-1] === null || arr2[j-1] === undefined){
                                return arr[j];
                            }else{
                                return arr2[j];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            alert("from \n"+ findMovedFrom(outOld,newArr) + "\nto before\n" + newArr[(newArr.indexOf(findMovedFrom(outOld,newArr))) + 1] +  "\n");
        }
    });

   </script>
```